# How to get array min value

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have multidimensional array and me need to get a minimum value.

Array may be `[65,4,4,511,5,[[54,54[.[.[..].].]]` and so on.

example code

```
<?php 

$arr = [5, 1 , 2, 3, [1,5,59,47,58,[0,12,562]]];
function NumMin($arr)
{
    $num = '';
    foreach ($arr as $item => $i) {
        if(is_array($i)){
            NumMin($i);
        }
        else{
                $num .= $i.',';

            }
    }


    $num .= $num;
    return $num;

}
$g = NumMin($arr);
var_dump($g);
```

I need to get `0`

Comment: flatten the array using a technique from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array) then find the min in the array using `min()`

Comment: e.g.: `$min = min(...new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input)));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function to flatten a given array (makes it one-dimensional).

And use simply `min()` function for getting the desired output after.

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use (&$res){
    $res[]=$v; 
});

echo min($res);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QA0Yt)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$GLOBALS["min"] = 999999; //min value int
$arr = [[[5,6],7],9,7,5, 1 , 2, 3, [1,5,59,47,58,[1,12,562]]];
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'NumMin');

function NumMin($item)
{
    if(intval($item) <= intval($GLOBALS["min"]))
    {
        $GLOBALS["min"] = intval($item); 
    }


}
// The end, $GLOBALS["min"] will have the least value
```

echo $GLOBALS["min"];
    ?>

Comment: [It doesn't works](https://3v4l.org/5l8bC). Should be `1` as output in your case.

Comment: Sorry, do not initialize at 0, but at 99999 (
very large number)